# Catch dangerous access to variables without dollar sign

Tags: css, sass, stylelint

I usually declare my scss variables at the top of my local style sheets and I access them in my custom rules.
The problem is that if I accidentally forget to reference the variable using dollar sign notation, the scss parser won't be able to replace the variable with its value thus leading to incorrect css styles.
As trivial as it might seem, this error took me hours to figure out.

I tried to setup `stylelint` extending `stylelint-config-standard` and I am using the `stylelint-scss` plugin, however none of them is able to catch such trivial yet dangerous error (or maybe I just couldn't find the proper rule).

```
$translateOffset: -10px !default;
$translateTarget: 0 !default;

@keyframes pbTranslateX {
  from {
    transform: translate(translateOffset); // oops I forgot the $ sign
  }

  to {
    transform: translate($translateTarget);
  }
}
```

I almost certain that there is a way out there to help catch this developer mistake.

Comment: You can always run the resulting CSS through a css validator.

Comment: @MrLister please elaborate. What can a CSS validator bring?